# Ajax call not working from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement to show/hide a text area when I click on the checkbox. 
If the checkbox is checked I have to call a controller which returns a string and the same need to be displayed in the text area .

1. My query is is it okay to return a string from the action result to display multiline text in my text area?
2. Another problem I am facing is the ajax call is not getting called. 
   I am getting alert inside my check box click event but the controller is not getting called.

I have the below action result and the ajax call.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetText(int ID) {
  // Populate text 
  string text = "";
  text = db.Data
    .Where(q => q.QuestionID == ID)
    .Select(q => q.Text)
    .ToString();

  return Content(text);
}


$.ajax({
      url: "/Manage/GetText",
      dataType: "text/plain",
      method: "POST",
      data: "id=" + ID,
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        $("#Container_" + ID).show();
        $("#ttext_" + ID).html(result);
      }
```

Comment: `data: {ID: ID}` you need to pass a object as data more over your action result input parameter name case should match with the data object property name case.

Comment: Yer!!!!!its working.Can you suggect me for my first query1. is it okay to return a string from the action result to display multiline text in my text area?

Comment: Also should i change the return type to JSON from text/plain. My controller should return a multiline text

Comment: yes no problem with that approach at all

Comment: But your controller is not returning a JSON right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
$.post("/Manage/GetText",{ID: ID},function(result){
    alert(result);
    $("#Container_" + ID).show();
    $("#ttext_" + ID).html(result);
});
```

Comment: so here i need not specify the method and datatype

Comment: method is specified in `$.post` you also have `$.get` and no need of the datatype. It will handle, This is just a short hand form of what you have written

Answer (score 0):

change the `data` of `ajax` to the following

```
data : {ID: ID}
```

here in `json` object first `ID` is the property name and `ID` is the value